# Select from two tables with same column name mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, search

I have two tables I need to `select * from`. Im building a search code.

This is my query:

```
SELECT articles.*, news.* FROM articles, news WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' OR short_description LIKE '%$search%' OR author LIKE '%$search%' OR date LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT 15
```

I get this error:

```
Error
SQL query: Documentation


SELECT articles.*, news.* FROM articles, news WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' OR short_description LIKE '%$search%' OR author LIKE '%$search%' OR date LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT 15
MySQL said: Documentation

#1052 - Column 'title' in where clause is ambiguous
```

Comment: `WHERE articles.title LIKE ...`

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  It seems quite clear.  Also, why are you not using proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: to paraphrase what mysql is trying to say to you: _which `title` are you referring to? title from the article? or title from the news?_

Comment: I understood but I need them referring to the title each one to his own title how do I do that?

Comment: So Use aliases.

Comment: Also, given that MySQL is a relational database management system, it's a little odd that we're not describing any relation here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
SELECT a.*, n.* FROM articles a,
join news n on a.____ = n.______
WHERE a.title LIKE '%$search%' OR a.short_description LIKE '%$search%' 
OR n.author LIKE '%$search%' OR n.date LIKE '%$search%' 
LIMIT 15
```

You need to add Alias', I have guessed below what each of the tables the LIKE statements could be pulling from. You'll need to replace the a.___ with the right identifier yourself.

It may also be worth changing the old JOIN Syntax.